# Is there a way to write an LLVM front end compiler in C#?

Tags: c#, llvm

Is there a way to write an LLVM front end compiler in C#?

Comment: Modern (2021) answer is: https://github.com/microsoft/LLVMSharp and https://ice1000.org/llvm-cs/en/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why not.  There is a [language reference for LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) and as long as you are compliant with the language, there is no reason you can't write something in C# which will parse that language and either:

- Produce output based on the language (like a real-time interpreter)
- Create an assembly in C# which will execute the LLVM instructions

This isn't to say it will be *easy*, but it *can* be done.

Comment: Update for people from the future: Do not try to write a bitcode/ll parser/writer for C#, instead use some bindings such as [llvm-fs](https://github.com/keithshep/llvm-fs) or [LLVM.NET](https://github.com/aaronrandolph/LLVM.NET) (which I have not tried).

Comment: http://www.llvmsharp.org -- disclaimer, I'm the author of these.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways. You could P/Invoke LLVM's C bindings (more than enough for implementing a compiler backend), or you could write your own wrapper with C++/CLI.

I used Clang-generated XML AST dump for LLVM's C bindings headers to generate .NET bindings for them automatically. But it is not possible to do it any longer, as XML AST printer had been removed from Clang, with no replacement available.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to have a LLVM compiler FOR C#, [Mono 2.6 can use LLVM](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_LLVM)

Comment: No, I'm looking to write a LLVM compiler IN C#.

Comment: If you want, I'll delete this anwser